# Selenium: Change By-instance or concat two By-instances

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, findby

Is it possible to combine/concat two Bys?

If I have one `By`

```
By parentBy = new By.xpath(".//div[@class='parent']")
```

and another `By`

```
By childBy = new By.xpath(".//div[@class='child']")
```

is it possible to concat the two Bys to a new one that has this xpath?

```
By combinedBy = new By.xpath(".//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='child']")
```

Something like

```
By combinedBy1 = parentBy + childBy
By combinedBy2 = parentBy.Concat(childBy)
```

---

Usecase:

We use the page object model.

Now I have a table as kind of child page object model. This table should have a method to select some data. Because of some html-structure issues (it is third party) I have to xpath a cell of the table that is child of a div (the row) by checking for a class of the cell and the text/content of this cell.

Comment: As for me, it doesn't make any sense because you can write any complex xpath without combining `By`. Can you give an example where you want to apply your combined `By`?

Comment: whats the need of it?In which case you need to do so.Plz elaborate as  may be there is some straight forward simple solution.

Comment: If your expressions are too long, you might prefer to save it in variables and concatenate the strings and "/" to combine them.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to what @SiKing said, I would also recommend looking at the `ByChained` class (see [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByChained.html) for javadocs).

Example on how to use it:

```
driver.findElements(new ByChained(By.id("product-table"), By.className("quantity")));
```

Not sure if this addresses OP's question directly, but still very useful.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

1. You can do something like:

   ```
   WebElement parentEl = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""))
   WebElement childEl = parentEl.findElement(By.className(""))
   ```
2. Use the PageFactory `@FindBys`. See [Selenium PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) and [Selenium API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBys.html).

Comment: Returns a WebElement and not a By object.